# Can menstruation disorders be in any way linked to an elevated intake of sodium and/or calcium?

Tags: nutrition, menstruation

Can menstruation disorders be in any way linked to an elevated intake of sodium and/or calcium? This excerpt got me wondering about that. I didn't find anything on Google that would corraborate this connection.

> Comparative analysis of the menstrual function
> among women indicates that the most disorders had
> women among the first group who for a long time used
> the higher mineralization water. These women often
> have either a short menstrual cycle (less than 21 days; p
> <0.01) or longer (more than 31 days; p <0.01), or irregular menstruation. Noteworthy in this group is more
> frequent ovarian failure function in the form of heavy
> and prolonged menstrual periods (p <0.01). Menstrual
> disorders function had women in both groups, most
> often in the first group (68,13 ± 2,94%; p <0.001).
> Individuals in this group had predominant disorder
> type hyper menstrual syndrome (32,64 ± 2,83%), while
> in the control group (11,02 ± 3,18%; p <0.001); As for
> other types of menstrual pathology, they also detected
> in women in the highly mineralized water.

*(from [here](http://www.ewg-board.eu/archiv-euromedica/archiv-euromedica-2-2014/Pages%20from%20archiv_euromedica_02_2014_maket_29_12_2014-14.pdf))*

Comment: The referenced article is certainly not a traditional western-style scientific article. For example, it seems to lack data and not control for obvious confounding factors (e.g. income).

Comment: I was unable to decipher the entire "Materials and Methods" section so I have no idea what this study actually consisted of.